# Strcmp Contradicts Printf in C

Tags: c, string, pointers

I am passing a pointer to a pointer to a void function, whose purpose is to dynamically allocate and create a string (containing a full file path).

At the end of the function, I check with a `printf(%s)` and the function seems to work perfectly (for the ~10 test files in my sample run). However, I check the pointer again in main, just after the void is called, and the result doesn't seem to be maintained.

At the end of the void function:

```
printf("%s\n", *ptr) returns usr/path/file
```

In main:

```
printf("%s\n", *ptr) returns usr/path/fil50(??
```

Stuff like this happens for several of the longer file paths (the shorter strings seem to be immune).  I create the string inside the void function with strcpy and strcat on two char buffers (for directory path and file name).

The really weird thing is - I added `strcmp` and `strlen` checks on the `*ptr` strings in the two places (at the end of the void function and in main), and:

1. strlen is the same for the two, even though the externally printed string is clearly longer! See the above example. I can clearly tell because each string is printed on a new line.
2. strcmp returns 0, even though the strings printed are obviously different.

I cannot account for this behavior...The change in *ptr within and outside the function is one thing, but how can printf and strcmp contradict each other??

I have not been able to find anyone else who has experienced this, and would be grateful for any help.

EDIT- I should have mentioned the void function is trying to replace an existing intra-main operation that wastes a lot of memory (calling sprintf on a massive buffer). Frankly I was just asking a general question about contradiction between strcmp and printf, but am certainly willing to provide more evidence.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
char buff[MASSIVE_SIZE];
    sprintf(buff, "%s/%s", dir, path->d_name);
    char **ptr = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*));
    make_full_path(dir, path->d_name, ptr);
    printf("external, strcmp:%d\n%s\n", strlen(*ptr), *ptr);
    printf("strcmp=%d\n", strcmp(buff, *ptr));
}


void make_full_path (const char *dir_name, char *other_name, char **pptr){
int len_one = strlen(dir_name);
int len_two = strlen(other_name);

char dest[len_one+2];
strcpy(dest, dir_name);
dest[len_one] = '/';
dest[len_one+1] = '\0';
char src[len_two+1];
strcpy(src, other_name);
src[len_two] = '\0';
*pptr = strcat(dest, src);
printf("internal, strlen=%d:\n%s\n", strlen(*pptr), *pptr);
}
```

Comment: Impossible to tell what's wrong without seeing the code. My guess is you didn't allocate enough space.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read about [Ask] and about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  There really isn't much we can do unless you show us some code that reproduces the problem — and it will probably be easy for us to help you once you do show the code.  Note the 'minimal' part of MCVE; that's important.

Comment: Are you allocating space based on a measurement with strlen? Do you add 1 for the null terminator?

Comment: This sort of thing can occur if you're returning a pointer to local memory instead of dynamically allocated (`malloc()` et al) memory.  It is less usual with dynamically allocated memory.  We have to reserve judgement until we can see your allocation code, etc. ––– One surprising thing to try: print twice in the function.  If you get different results, you're almost certainly dealing with local stack memory that was returned by a function.

Comment: The code has been added. Voting to reopen.

Comment: what's the preferred venue for high level theoretical questions? in this case, under what conditions would strcmp return 0 for two strings that are printed differently? (the answer could be none, but still, does such a forum exist on this website?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, I check the pointer again in main, just after the void is called, and the result doesn't seem to be maintained.

This could mean only one thing: you are returning a pointer to local. This is undefined behavior:

```
char dest[len_one+2];
...
*pptr = strcat(dest, src); // Passing a local back to main
```

Replace it with a call of `malloc` will fix the problem:

```
char dest[len_one+strlen(other_name)+2];
...
strcat(dest, src);
*pptr = malloc(strlen(dest)+1);
strcpy(*pptr, dest);
```

Comment: read the first sentence, he said he does allocate memory

Comment: This was also my first assumption, but we really need to see the code to give a proper answer.

Comment: @MeikVtune I suspect OP calls VLA a "dynamic allocation". There's simply no other explanation.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Mind explaining what VLA means? Not an expert in C, more like a beginner :)

Comment: @MeikVtune It's variable length array, as in `char *make(int n) {char x[n]; return x; }`

Comment: @MeikVtune: VLA is 'variable length array' – an array that is allocated local to a function with a size not fixed at runtime.  For example: `int func(int n) { int arr[n]; … }` would be a VLA.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thank you! Yes that seems like the most likely explanation(Thank god i've been thought that it doesn't work before making the mistake).

Comment: I don't believe this is the issue. As I mentioned, the shorter strings are returned perfectly after the function call in main! For the longer strings, some bogus characters are added. However, even for these cases, the internal debug check does not reflect the external problem

Comment: @MikePalmice When shorter strings work but longer strings don't, it's precisely the symptom of undefined behavior. Give `malloc` a try. I edited the answer to show you how to do it.

Comment: @MeikVtune I knew it! (see OP's edit, he's using a VLA and returning it to the caller).

Comment: thanks everybody. very helpful and enlightening

Comment: @MikePalmice You are welcome! Give the answer a try. If it works, please consider accepting the answer by clicking the grey check mark next to it. This would let others know that the problem is solved, and earn you a new badge on Stack Overflow. Good luck with your project!